# How can I use Spring Cloud Task with modular Spring Batch jobs?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I've developed couple of `Spring Batch` jobs in `Spring Boot` web application. For easier maintenance, I used `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)` like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value="first.batch.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public ApplicationContextFactory firstJobs() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(FirstModule.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value="second.batch.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public ApplicationContextFactory secondJobs() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(SecondModule.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

and I have `@Configuration` classes, one for every `Job` defined respectively in base directories of modules. Everything works fine, but now I want to setup `Spring Cloud Dataflow` UI to have some basic monitoring of my `Jobs`.

The problem is, when I try to add `@EnableTask` annotation to this class `BatchConfiguration`, `Spring` is not associating job execution with task execution. It is only working, when I run tests (`@SpringBatchTest`).

I also tried to add `@EnableTask` annotation to `FirstJobConfiguration` class instead, and also add it to both `BatchConfiguration` and `First|JobConfiguration`, but with no effect. I also went through official documentation, but found nothing.

Is it possible to use `Spring Cloud Task` with modular `Spring Batch` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Spring Batch` application can be converted into a Spring Cloud Task application and be managed using Spring Cloud Data Flow.

You should be able to use `EnableTask` in your SpringBoot application along with `EnableBatchProcessing` in your configuration.

Please see the [SCDF sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/batch/file-ingest) which demonstrates this scenario.

Comment: thank you for response and this is completely correct, but once i define jobs as modular, then they run each in its own child application context and then `Spring Cloud Task` cannot associate `Task` execution with `Batch` execution